# Deleting multiple songs from new itunes playlist

Tags: itunes

How do I remove multiple songs at once in a new iTunes playlist? I know how to remove songs one at a time, but is there a way to remove multiple songs at once?

Answer (score -2):

Select the songs that you want to delete by holding <kbd>Command</kbd>, then either right click and select "Remove from Playlist", or press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Pressing command+delete will *delete* selected songs from your iTunes library. If you only want to remove the songs from the playlist you can just press delete.